# How to pass a parameter and redraw a table with jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have datatables with the name VendorClinet, I want to filter the table, I send the filter using select, the problem here is the table doesn't want to change after filtering, I've tried using reload but the table still doesn't change

```
$('#status').on('change', function() {
         var status = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          url:"{{route('vendorInfo')}}"+"/"+"?status="+status,
          success:function(data){
               VendorClient.ajax.reload(null, false );
          }
         });
    });
```

and this my dattables code

```
var VendorClient = $("#tAdmin").DataTable({
     order: [ 0, "asc" ],
      processing: true,
      serverSide: false,
      ajax: "{{route('vendorInfo')}}",
      columns: [
        {
          data: "name",
          name: "name",
          orderable:false
        },
        {
          data: "vendor_type",
          name: "vendor_type",
          orderable:false
        },
        {
          data: "mode",
          name: "mode",
          orderable:false
        },
        {
          data: "status",
          name: "status",
          orderable:false
        },

        },
      ]
    });
```

Comment: How about VendorClient.ajax.reload()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option if you want to pass data to the server.

```
ajax: {
   url: "{{route('vendorInfo')}}",
   data: function (d){
      d.status = $('#status').val();
   },
   method: 'GET'
}
```

Use the following code to reload the table when status changes.

```
$('#status').on('change', function() {
   VendorClient.ajax.reload();
});
```